# How to throw 404 Error in web.xml?

Tags: java, web.xml, servlet-filters

If my URL Pattern matches /aaaa/* then i need to throw 404 Error, is there any way to throw it directly in deployment descriptor or do i need to write filter class and thorw it in that servlet filter class?

Comment: Yes create a fliter for that. You cannot throw something in xmls

Comment: Although, it is possible not to create any more filter and have it redirect to a specific jsp page instead but this is not the ideal...

Answer (score 0):

As you might know, 404 is for "Resource Not Found" which is thrown by the Web Container if no resource is found.

I think for you the best way is to filter any request for /aaaa/* and redirect to a meaningful error page.